# why form is submitted while new window is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have the javascript function to open a new window and based on the value selected its populated the parent window field .But the problem is while open the new window the form is submitted .I just didn't attach the validation part. Can any body tell what might be the problem.

```js
$(function() {
//Popup window for Nationlity 
function nationalityPopUp() {
        var nationalUrl="%bind(:9)";
     new_Window = window.open(nationalUrl,"","width=220, height=500, left=250, top=50, scrollbars, resizable"); 
}
  
//Disable Parent Window
function parent_disable() {
 if(new_Window && !new_Window.closed){ 
  new_Window.focus(); 
 }
}
```

```html
<body onclick="parent_disable();">
 <form name="Basicinfo" id="Basicinfo" method="post" action="%bind(:8)" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

       <input type="text" name="Nationality" id="Nationality" value ="" />
                <input type="image" src="%bind(:14)" name="Ntlylkp" onclick="nationalityPopUp();"  />
               </br></br>*Country Of Residency:                  
       <input type="text" name="Residency_country" id="Residency_country" value ="" onblur="validateResCountry(value)"/>
    <input type="image" src="%bind(:14)" name="Cntrylkp" onclick="countryPopUp();"/>
                </br></br>*National Id:
        <input id="Emirates_Id" name="Emirates_Id" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;">
              </br></br>*Marital Status:
             <select name="marital_status" id="marital_status">
      :%bind(:3);
                </select>            
            </br> </br> *Regional Preference:
             <select name="religious" id="religious">
      :%bind(:4);
                </select>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit And Next" style="float:right" >

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` `false` while the for is submitted with `jquery` -

```
$('#Basicinfo').on('submit', function() {
     if (some check needed) { // if want to add any check to submit the form or not
         return false;
     }
})
```

Comment: @Bose the problem is the page there is a prompt button where it is redirect to another  page as popup and if i click on this popup it is submit the page .so my question how i can restrict that page to be submit.

Comment: Page is not submitted, it is refreshed. Forms get submitted.

Comment: it is calling the formvalidation() function upon click on prompt button.But actually it has to call after click on submit button

Comment: WHere is the prompt button?

Comment: @BOSE in the naionality input tag there is a image of search button to open a new window